Proof of equivalent definitions of normal extensions
Let $F \supset k$ be an algebraic extension.
We have these two characterizations of a normal extension:
a) For every $k$-homomorphism $\sigma: F \to \overline{k}$, we have $\sigma(F) \subset F$
b) If an irreducible polynomial $f \in k[x]$ has a root in $F$, then it has every root in $F$.
I want to prove a) $\Rightarrow$ b), any help will be very welcome.
I will write my line of thought, I apologize for any confusion.
First preliminary observation: as we have $\sigma(F) \subset F$, we can say that $\sigma$ is a function from $F$ to $F$, i.e., a $k$-endomorphism $\sigma: F \to F$. As the extension is algebraic, we can conclude that $\sigma$ is a $k$-automorphism. This way, $\sigma(F) = F$.
Ok, next step.
Take an irreducible polynomial $f \in k[x]$ with one root $u \in F$. We can consider the extension $k(u) \supset k$.
We have the homomorphism
$\alpha: k[x]/(f) \rightarrow k(u)$
$\overline{f} \mapsto f(u)$
Now consider another root of this polynomial $f$, let's call it $v \in \overline{k}$.
I want a function $\sigma$ that maps $k(u)$ to $\overline{k}$ such that $\sigma(u) = v$.
So, consider the homomorphism
$\beta: k[x]/(f) \to \overline{k}$
$\overline{f} \mapsto f(v)$
If we define
$\sigma := \beta \circ \alpha^{-1}$, we have a $k$-homomorphism
$\sigma: k(u) \to \overline{k}$
$u \mapsto v$
Next thing to consider. We have the following tower:
\begin{array}{c}
F \\
| \\
k(u) \\
| \\
k
\end{array}
Since the extension $F \supset k$ is algebraic, $F \supset k(u)$ is also algebraic. So we can extend the homomorphism $\sigma$.
\begin{array}{ccc}
F & \xrightarrow{\lambda} & \overline{k} \\
| & & | \\
| & & | \\
k(u) & \xrightarrow{\sigma} & \overline{k}
\end{array}
But $\lambda(u) = v$ and, as by hypothesis, $\lambda(F) = F$, we conclude that $v \in F$.
Please tell me if there are any mistakes, what needs to be improved, and what isn't clear...
